# Get streaming data with flume - advice

Tags: flume, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm working on a project and I would like some advice. I need to get data in real time from a website (http://www.aishub.net) and store the data into HDFS (I use hortonworks). I have read different technologies to do that and I have found a tool called Flume (included with hortonworks).

My question is, what do you think about this? Is Flume can be helpful in my case? Or do you have another technology?

Thanks a lot for your response.

Simon !

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data-source/data-sink(Hadoop) as an inbuilt source/sink in Flume, using Flume you will be able to do the lift/load jobs easily by writing simple flume configurations.

Flume does provide you the fault tolerance in most cases, but you should really consider the time taken to learn something new before taking a decision.

IMHO, Flume is easier to learn.

Here are the list of available source/sinks in Flume. https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-sources